# rewriting a plugin for zepto.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, publish-subscribe, zepto

i'm trying to rewrite a little but awesome jquery plugin for [zepto.js](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto):

https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/pubsub.js

i don't think its a ploblem, because the syntax is nearly similar, but im struggling a little bit at this part of the pubsub plugin:

```
cache[topic] && d.each(cache[topic], function(){
    this.apply(d, args || []);
});
```

my console says something like:

> TypeError: Result of expression
>   'd.each' [undefined] is not a
>   function.

some hints how to get this working?

Comment: I've written a post about some [differences between jQuery and Zepto](http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/jquery-zepto-differences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out. .each didn't work with zepto.

here is my rewritten zepto plugin:

https://github.com/martinjuhasz/pubsub-zepto

Comment: For the record, zepto supports .each() as of v0.4 and $.each() as of v0.7 -- http://zeptojs.com/